# how to rotate the world nodes

Tags: node-editor

I have got this beautiful node from free addon. It creates sky and clouds. I want the ground to be move up and down as  my requirement.

[image]

[image]

So any suggestion how can i rotate the ground up and down. Thanks

Comment: This is equivalent to tilting the camera? Can we ask why?

Comment: (I had an aunt who wanted to photograph a reflection of a sunset in a lake from the side.. she wound up walking a very long way)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can move skyline in these. You can only control the movement of the sun/moon and other parameters.
[image: photo 1]

because these are similar to hdri, you can't really control such things, however there is some add on I forgot it's name that can make any hdri into a half dome, so it will close to a mesh.

P.S: I wanted to comment in stead of an answer, but I don't have enough reputation yet. because I may be wrong.

Comment: You _could_ put in a mapping node to rotate the world up in front of the camera, but you would have to know and take into account where the camera was panned to, otherwise the horizon would slope. Easier to tilt the camera?